# How do I fetch data for a machine running log with different 'start' 'stop' entry in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My application keeps track of machines that are 'started' and 'stopped' as many times as needed, and this information is saved in the same table with the fields `machine_ID`, `timestamp`, `entry_type`(start/stop).

A start creates a row, and a stop creates a different row.

```
Sample start row : M1 - 2019-06-27 12:08:30 - 'start'
Sample stop row :  M1 - 2019-06-27 14:30:05 - 'stop'
```

I need to be able to display:

1) All currently running machines (Machines that don't have a stop entry after the latest start entry)

2)A timeline of the previous machine activity preferably chronologically. Eg Machine 1 started: 09AM stopped 10 AM, Machine 2 started: 1pm, stopped 2pm, etc.

I imagine a result table as follows would be what I need but I can't understand how to build a query to fetch it.

```
'M1 - 2019-06-27 12:08:30 - 'start''
'M1 - 2019-06-27 14:30:05 - 'stop''
'M1 - 2019-06-27 16:00:00 - 'start''
'M1 - 2019-06-27 16:30:00 - 'stop''
'M2 - 2019-06-27 16:00:00 - 'start''
'M2 - 2019-06-27 16:30:00 - 'stop''
```

I plan tp use PHP to parse through such a table.

I am unable to alter the table structure in any way.

I believe the general principle behind solutions to this kind of problem has been well documented, however, not knowing how to refer to it, I am unable to do my own research.

Thanks.

Comment: if you sort your query by `timestamp` descending and `limit` the result to `1` row, you will get the last entry for a machine. if this entry is `start`, the machine is not stopped.

Comment: `SELECT * from tableName where machineID like 'M2' order by timestamp DESC LIMIT 1` I assumed tableName, machineID and timestamp as possible column names. This should have the result: `'M2','2019-06-27 16:30:00','stop'`

Comment: If you want me to write a more explanatory answer, I would need to know more about the actual table structure.

Comment: @2x2p Thanks. I like the idea of sorting and limiting to 1, but this would mean I first get a list of all machines in this 'machineshedules_tbl' and then fire a query for each one of them to see if the last entry for that machine is a start or stop. I did wonder if that is possible to do within one trip to mysql instead. The table itself doesn't contain much else., just another column ' batch_ID' that ties these entries to a particular batch run. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did expect you keep track of all machine IDs somewhere so yes. If you don't have this you can also get all rows sorted by timestamp descending and in PHP filter out the IDs. So if you find an ID that you already had a status for you skip it and proceed to the next row until the last row. Than you have a list of ID and their last status.

Comment: @2x2p I'll be doing as you've suggested, thank you. Would you be able to point me towards a way to accomplish my other requirement of essentially formulating a timeline for past machine activity?

Comment: what do you mean by timeline? Should this be a graph?